# Is it safe to pass a query with no parameters to PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I am quite new to Java, so for sure this is gonna be a silly question.

I often read that one must be aware of the risk of SQL injection when dealing with queries treated as String. I also read that using PreparedStatements is a good way for preventing such risk, but they are generally used with positional parameters in the query (represented by question marks `?`).

What about the case when I just have a "constant" query with no parameters (i.e., I have no variables to insert in my query)? Do I still have to pass the query in the form
`"SELECT * from Table where col1 = ? and col2 = ?"`
to the PreparedStatement to prevent SQL injection?

Or could I just pass
`"SELECT * from Table where col1 = 123 and col2 = 'abc'"`
?

I have this code:

```
public ResultSet mySelectMethod(String query, Connection conn) {
    ResultSet rset = null;
    try {
        PreparedStatement st = conn.PreparedStatement(query);   //I am unsure about this assignment
        rset = st.executeQuery();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return rset;
}
...
...
// method call:
String myQuery = "SELECT colA FROM table_name WHERE table_id = 192837465";
ResultSet myResultSet = mySelectMethod(myQuery, myConn);
```

Is this safe or are there any issues?

Comment: The danger is in inserting external input directly into your SQL query. There's no security problem executing a query with safe values already included.

Comment: "_risk of SQL injection when dealing with queries treated as String_" The risk is when you take some external input like from a text box on a web page and directly put it into the String which you are not doing. This is fine.

Comment: Ok, so basically if no one is going to use my method with external input (I only call it to execute fixed queries), there are no problems. Right? Thanks everybody!

Comment: The answers here covered the question pretty well. I really really do recommend you take the time to check out how EASILY SQL Injection (and lots of other injections) work. Because it is a VERY common problem, it is probaly THE easiest and most common attack vector. And it's usually quite easy to prevent, but most importantly: to always have in mind when designing software.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are not passing any parameter to your query, you do not have the risk of SQL Injection. Also, you do not need `PreparedStatement` for your case. You can use `Statement` instead.

```
String query = "SELECT * from Table where col1 = 123 and col2 = 'abc'";

try (Statement st = conn.createStatement()) {
    ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);

    while (rs.next()) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Apart from this, as you can see in the code above, you should try using [try-with-resorces statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) which closes the resource automatically.

Comment: Thank you!! Can I use Statement also for insert/update/delete? Or is this only possible through PreparedStatement?

Comment: You are most welcome! You can use [`Statement#executeUpdate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)) for `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` statement.